# Nash Bargaining Solution Axioms

Tags: game-theory

For each of the four axioms characterizing the Nash bargaining solution, construct a bargaining solution that violates that axiom but satisfies the remaining three axioms.

EDIT: Here are the axioms I am referring to:

1. (Pareto Efficiency) A bargaining solution $f$ is Pareto efficient if for any bargaining problem $(U, d)$, there does not exist $(u_1, u_2) \in U$ such that $u_1\ge f_1(U, d)$ and $u_2\ge f_2(U,d)$, with at least one strict inequality.
2. (Symmetry) A bargaining solution $f$ is symmetric if for any symmetric bargaining problem $(U,d)$ ($(u1,u2) \in U$ if and only if $(u2,u1) \in U$ and $d_1 = d_2$), we have $f_1(U, d) = f_2(U, d)$.
3. Invariance to Linear Transformations
4. (Independence of Irrelevant Alternatives) A bargaining solution $f$ is independent if for any two bargaining problems $(U,d)$ and $(U',d)$ with $U' \subset U$ and $f(U,d) \in U'$, we have $f(U',d) = f(U,d)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are four counterexamples, one for each axiom.

1) Reverse the direction of preference and consider the *anti-Nash* solution 
$$f(U,d) = \arg \min (u_1-d_1)(u_2-d_2)$$

2) The *asymmetric* Nash solution is
$$f(U,d) = \arg \max (u_1-d_1)^k(u_2-d_2)^{1-k}$$
for some $k \ne 1/2$ in $[0,1]$.

3) The *egalitarian* solution is
$$f(U,d) = \arg \max \min \{ (u_1-d_1), (u_2-d_2)\}$$

4) The *Kalai-Smorodinski* solution is characterised by assuming monotonicity instead of IIA.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite clear for me how a Nash Bargaining solution is definied, following the 4 axiomatic definition.

By the way it is not very clear for me how to find the Nash Bargaining solution giving a bi-matrix. 
My understandin is that the key formula is the following

$
N = \max \limits_{v_{1},v_{2}} (v_{1} -d_{1})(v_{2} -d_{2})
$

So if I have a bimatrix like, so if I have a bimatrix

$ \left (
\begin{array}{ccc}
(1,-1) & (4,5) & (7,6)\\
(10,4) & (1,5) & (3,2)\\
(-1,1) & (10,5) & (2,6)\\
\end{array}
\right)
$

the disgreement point is $d=(3,3)$.

the solution should be

$
N = \max \limits_{v_{1},v_{2}} (v_{1} -3)(v_{2} -3) = (7-3)(6-3)= 12
$

Is this calculus correct or there is a gemoetric way to find a Nash bargaining solution?

Thanks for the help